# jQuery UI Autocomplete - Can I change where it searches?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement Autocomplete. So far I've overcome an obstacle: displaying custom information along the selectable items. For that matter, I'm passing the data with a JSON object. It's like this:

```
[{"codigo":"XL","descripcion":"Extra Large"},{"codigo":"M","descripcion":"Medium"},{"codigo":"S","descripcion":"Small"},{"codigo":"L","descripcion":"Large"}]
```

Now the initializing code is:

```
$this->template->add_js("$.getJSON(\"".base_url('talles/listar')."\", 
            function(data)
            {
                $('#txt_talle')
                    .autocomplete(
                        {
                            minLength: 0,
                            source: data,
                            focus: function(event, ui) { 
                                $('#txt_talle').val(ui.item.codigo);
                                return false;
                            },
                            select: function(event, ui) {
                                $('#txt_talle').val(ui.item.codigo);
                                return false;
                            }
                        })
                    .focus(function(){ $('#txt_talle').autocomplete('search') })
                    .data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
                        return $('<li></li>')
                        .data('item.autocomplete', item)
                        .append('<a>' + item.codigo + '|' + item.descripcion + '</a>')
                        .appendTo(ul);
                    }
                ;
            });", 'embed');
```

But now the problem is that the search is not working. I'm guessing that is does not work because it searches the objects, not *inside* the objects. I'd like to make it search among the item.codigo values. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the "source" option in the jQuery Autocomplete widget: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source. It either expects an array of strings, or an array of objects with `label` and `value` properties.

Try adding `label` and `value` properties to each item of the JSON array returned in the talles/listar server call.

Comment: Nice, I think this is enough for now. It searches the labels, but not the values. It would be very good if it searched both. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add it like this

```
$.getJSON("URL", function(data){
    var autoc = [];
    for (row in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(row)) {
            autoc[] = {
                'label': row.codigo,
                'value': row.descripcion
            }
        } 
    }
    $('#txt_talle').autocomplete({
            minLength: 0,
            source: autoc,
            focus: function(event, ui) { 
                $('#txt_talle').val(ui.item.codigo);
                return false;
            },
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $('#txt_talle').val(ui.item.codigo);
                return false;
            }
    }).focus(function(){
        $('#txt_talle').autocomplete('search')
    }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $('<li></li>')
        .data('item.autocomplete', item)
        .append('<a>' + item.codigo + '|' + item.descripcion + '</a>')
        .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

I'm creating a new object based  on your data object feeding the right label, value keys, as per [@Nick Fishman's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790104/jquery-ui-autocomplete-can-i-change-where-it-searches/12790283#12790283)

Comment: Thank you. The data is coming from a database, so I've worked it out selecting the fields with an alias.

Comment: yeah that's the better way to go about it, but in case you couldn't change the json data you can always re-map the object into a new one, glad I could belp